# How get p-value from wilcox.test statistics in R?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have an experiment in which I am calling `wilcox.test` in R for multiple times and gather statistic output. I compute the average of these statistics and then I want to convert it to p-value. What function should I call in `R` to get statistic of wilcox test as input and take a p-value as output?

```r
wilcox.statistics <- 692304.08
wilcox.pvalue <- whatFunction(wilcox.statistics) ???
```

Comment: It isn't a Wilcox test statistic if you've averaged several of them, among other things.

Comment: All of them are from the same experiment but I am changing a parameter in the experiment and then applying wilcox test again. Each time I get one wilcox statistic. Finally, I average all statistics to get a single statistic. Is this wrong?!

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: If you want only one p-value for some overall null hypothesis, first tell us what is that overall hypothesis. Then, get one p-value for each individual test, and then maybe combine the p-values. But maybe tell us what is your experiment and research question ...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is wrong.  Consider doing, say, 100 t-tests, with t-statistics around 1.5.  Averaging the t-statistics will give you 1.5, which won't reject the null hypothesis at typical levels of testing.   However, it is incredibly unlikely that you would get 100 out of 100 t-statistics above 1.0 by chance; this result would in itself be extremely powerful evidence of an effect, and would have a very, very low p-value.

Comment: "Is this wrong?!" Yes, that's wrong (you can't just make up how you think you might do stuff and hope it is doing what you want. That's not how any of this works.) You can (in suitable circumstances) calculate a p-value from a collection of independent tests of the *same* thing (not what you're doing) but you don't do it by averaging the test statistics and treating it like it was a single test statistic of that type.  There are many posts on site related to combining tests. However, if you're varying a parameter, I don't see what hypothesis you're even testing, it might not be suitable ...ctd

Comment: ctd ... What you have here is an example of an XY problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem -- that you're asking about how to solve an issue with your (apparently misguided) solution to an underlying problem you have. You should instead ask about the problem you were trying to solve in the first place and let us try to find a good solution to that problem.

Comment: Setting aside the analysis part of the question --- to answer the R code part of the question, you can use the `pwilcox()` function to go from the *W* statistic to the *p*-value.  But you have to be careful because the W statistic can be low or high depending on which variable is considered the first group, and the *wilcox.test()* function can implement an exact test, asymptotic test, or apply a continuity correction.  An example:  `A = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18); B = c(5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23); wilcox.test(A,B); W = 28; m = 9; n = 10; pwilcox(28, 9, 10, lower.tail=TRUE)*2.`

Comment: Thank you very much @SalMangiafico. This was the answer I was looking for.